# iPhone: anti-aliasing after rotating

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

I've load an image into narrow UIImageView - the width is 3px, the height is approx. 10

Then I've rotate the view - and I've got not pleasant picture, with visual distortion (like http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Anti-aliased-diamonds.png on the left part of picture).
Is any way to fix it? Does Quartz let anti-alias pictures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are rotating using UIView's `transform` property or rotating via the view's `layer`: you can produce superior looking results with quartz's apis directly.

you can create a higher quality image using a quartz image process which creates a new image and specify high quality with anti-aliasing for the transform and rendering.

this image process could be implemented many ways, such as `CGContextRotateCTM` followed by `CGContextDrawImage`, then accessing the new image with `CGBitmapContextCreateImage`.

alternatively, you may prefer to draw the image directly to the context rather than creating an intermediate.

Comment: try using `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo` in this post as a starting point: http://renzoverleysen.tumblr.com/post/459850033/tutorial-full-resolution-iphone-photo-apps